# LWC - When tabbing in Datatable, view scrolls up

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, accordion

I am creating a LWC (non-Aura) using lightning-accordion and lightning-datatable to display a list of contact related items.  There are several accordion sections.  I am able to do for each section:

- Populate the table
- Update and save the data back into SF
- Refresh the table with the update/new data

The problem is when I go into the table to edit a field and tab to the next field the page scrolls up, just a few lines.  It scrolls up for every tab into the next field.

If I open up one accordion, then it does not scroll but the scrolling behavior is inconsistent.  Some times it will scroll and not.  If I open two accordions and tab in one table, then the page scrolls with every tab, very consistent.  What do I need to not make the page scroll?

Here is a screenshot of the [problem](https://youtu.be/7-kx2MnG5ng).

Setup the accordion and iterate through a list of items

```
<template>
  <template if:true={displayClasses}>
      <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle} active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <template for:each={subjectCategories} for:item="subject">
          <c-degree-plan-subject
            key={subject}
            subject={subject}
            subject-classes={subjectClasses}
            onrenderingchild={handleRenderingChild}
            onclassupdate={handleClassUpdate}
            onrefresh={handleRefresh}></c-degree-plan-subject>
        </template>
      </lightning-accordion>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

Setup an accordion section with a data table.  The modal is used to create a new record.

```
<!-- degreePlanSubject.html -->
<template>
  <lightning-accordion-section name={subject} label={subject}>
    <lightning-datatable
      key-field="Id"
      data={classes}
      columns={columns}
      onsave={handleSave}
      draft-values={draftValues}></lightning-datatable>
  </lightning-accordion-section>
  <template if:true={isModalOpen}>
    <section
      role="dialog"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-label="Modal to create a new class record"
      aria-modal="true"
      aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
      class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
      <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <header class="slds-modal__header slds-modal__header_empty">
          <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
          </button>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
          <c-create-degree-plan-class oncreateddpclass={handleModalClose} oncancelddpclass={handleModalClose} subject={subject} tid={recordId}></c-create-degree-plan-class>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer"></footer>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
  </template>
</template>
```